how can a ganglion be defined as cluster of neuron bodies when it has interneurons?
Let alone the presynaptic button existing there as well, how is a whole interneuron existing there not contradict the definition ?

Can you explain what you see as a contradiction? I don't understand.

1-ganglion: mass of neuron bodies. 2-an interneuron: a body+ an axon+ a terminal. 3-some ganglia do have interneurons, thus have body+axon+terminal.     Conclussion: contradiction. It's pretty straight forward.

Please don't tell people that ask for clarification that something is "pretty straightforward". Your question is badly presented. First there is no question in the body. The title of a question serves a different purpose and is quite distinct from the question itself (and should start with a capital letter). This renders your single sentence  ungrammatical — the first clause lacks an active verb. And your clarification should come in the question itself, not the comment. It would still lack sufficient context. You need to reference your definition, and explain where "there" is.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In general ganglions are cluster of cell bodies . Presence of inter neuron in ganglion is a bit rare . Grossly they contains cell body.

Merriam Webster defines an "ocean" as:

the whole body of salt water that covers nearly three fourths of the surface of the earth

So, oceans are bodies of salt water. Yet, oceans also contain fish. They contain some mammals. They contain some human-produced trash. We might consider the ocean as "containing" things like islands that are mostly surrounded by ocean but are not themselves ocean. This does not create a problem for our definition of "ocean".
If someone defines a ganglion as "a cluster of neuronal cell bodies" they are telling you that you can expect to find a bunch of neuronal cell bodies there. They are not claiming you will find nothing else there. At minimum you will need to find some parts of axons and dendrites, because these are connected to cell bodies and there's no way to have a cluster of cell bodies without including at least parts of the things connected to them. They're also going to contain non-neuronal support cells (glia), and yes, can contain interneurons, synapses, etc. Interneurons, by the way, are neurons. That doesn't mean they're not clusters of neuronal cell bodies any more than the existence of fish means that the ocean is not a body of salty water.
